# When and when not to use "was"

Tags: grammaticality, absolute-constructions

> About a hundred people had already gathered, **a guard rail** the only thing separating them from the crater's edge.

Is it not more proper to say  "About a hundred people had already gathered, a guard rail **was** the only thing separating them from the crater's edge."?

It naturally sounds more clear in my opinion when was is used.

Comment: To push that *was* in there, use period instead of the comma. Then "A guard rail was ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an [absolute nominative](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_absolute). That construction usually includes a nominal with a dependent adjectival phrase, but, as in this case, it can also include a nominal ("a guard rail") with a dependent appositive ("the only thing separating them from the crater's edge").

That construction is correct, but feel free to make it into a finite clause by adding "was". Just watch out for the [comma splice](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_splice) (if you care about such things).

Comment: The “omitted” word would be *being* (a participle) — not *was*: *About a hundred people had already gathered, a guard rail being the only thing separating them from the crater's edge.*

Comment: @TinfoilHat Yes, inserting "being" would make it the more typical nominal + adjectival phrase. I only mentioned "was" because OP specifically asked about that in his question.